# Outputting users answers and the correct answers in the method "void quizResults()"

Tags: java, arrays

```
class QuizMethods {
    String [] questions = new String [20];
    String [] answers   = new String [20];
    String [] correctAnswers = new String [20];
    int score; 
    void fillArrays() {    
        questions[0] = " Who is the lead guitarist of Led Zeppelin?";  
        correctAnswers[0] = "Jimmy Page";

        questions[1] = "Who is the lead singer of Led Zeppelin?"; 
        correctAnswers[1]= "Robert Plant";

        questions[2] = "Who is the lead guitarist of Pink Floyd?";  
        correctAnswers[2] = "David Gilmour";

        questions[3] = "Who is the bassist and main lyricist of Pink Floyd?"; 
        correctAnswers[3]= "Roger Waters";

        questions[4] = "Under which category of music are Pink Floyd entitled too?";  
        correctAnswers[4] = "Soft Rock";

        questions[5] = "Under which category of music are Metallica entitled too?"; 
        correctAnswers[5]= "Trash Metal";

        questions[6] = "Who is the lead guitarist of Metallica?";  
        correctAnswers[6] = "Kirk Hammet";

        questions[7] = "Who is the lead singer and rhythm guitarist of Metallica?"; 
        correctAnswers[7]= "James Hetfield";

        questions[8] = "Who is the lead guitarist of Guns n Roses?";  
        correctAnswers[8] = "Slash";

        questions[9] = "Who is the lead singer of Guns n Roses?"; 
        correctAnswers[9]= "Axl Rose";

        questions[13] = "Under which category of music are Guns n Roses entitled too?"; 
        correctAnswers[13]= "Hard Rock";

        questions[11] = "Who is the bassist of Guns n Roses?"; 
        correctAnswers[11]= "Duff McKagan";

        questions[12] = "Name the biggest and most sold album of Pink Floyd";  
        correctAnswers[12] = "The Wall";

        questions[13] = "Under which category of music are ZZ Top entitled too?"; 
        correctAnswers[13]= "Blues Rock";

        questions[14] = "Who is the lead guitarist and vocalist of ZZ Top?";  
        correctAnswers[14] = "Billy Gibbons";

        questions[15] = "Who is considered as the king of blues?"; 
        correctAnswers[15]= "BB King";

        questions[16] = "Who was the lead singer for the popular band Queen?";  
        correctAnswers[16] = "Freddie Mercury";

        questions[17] = "Who was the lead singer for the Heavy Metal band Black Sabbath?"; 
        correctAnswers[17]= "Ozzy Osbourne";

        questions[18] = "Who is the lead guitarist of Dire Straits?";  
        correctAnswers[18] = "Mark Knopfler";

        questions[19] = "Complete the sentence.Alphaville released the song named _______ _______ in September 1984."; 
        correctAnswers[19]= "Forever Young";
    }

    void takeQuiz(){
        String answer;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.print(questions[i] + "\nAnswer: ");
            answer = Keyboard.readString();
            answers[i] = answer;

            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswers[i])) {
                score++;
            } else {
                score--;
            }
        }
    }

    void quizResults() {
    }

    void performanceComment() {
    }

    void exit() {
    }

    void menu() {
        System.out.println("1. Take Quiz");
        System.out.println("2. Quiz Results");
        System.out.println("3. Performance Comment");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");
        System.out.print("Choose from the above:");
        byte menu = Keyboard.readByte();
        switch(menu) {

        case 1: 
            takeQuiz();
            break;

        case 2:
            quizResults();
            break;

        case 3:
            performanceComment();
            break;

        case 4: 
            exit();        
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to output the users answers and the correct answers in the method `void quizResults()`. I don't know what to use to do this.
How can I end the program in the method `void exit()`?

Comment: Please be more specific about what the actual problem is that you're encountering. We're happy to help, but this reads a lot like you've just dumped your homework here and are expecting us to fix it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stored the user's answers and you have the correct answers in arrays.
The indexes should line up, so you can just cycle through the arrays and output to screen.

Something like:

```
public void quizResults(){
    for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){
        System.out.println("Question: #" + i);
        System.out.println("You answered: " + answers[i]);
        System.out.println("Correct answer: " + correctAnswers[i]);
}
```

I also recommend you put in a default case for the switch statement. If the user enters something other than 1,2,3 or 4, you need to handle it in an appropriate way (i.e. message stating that they entered an invalid option.)